# Laravel: Sum inside loop using variables from another table

Tags: laravel

I am doing a sales report chart for a small POS project and I got stuck in the part where I need to sum each category in the sales_item table. (I think grouBy() function will not work, since sometimes some category are not yet in the sales_item table and I need to get 0 for categories that are not yet in the table.

what I want to do is sum each category in the sales_table by doing:
1st: Get the names of categories in the category table.
2nd: Use the name of the category with loop to sum sales_item respectively.
3rd: return the array of categories with their sum.

here is the code I got stuck: 
EDIT: Solved it with this:

```
  public function getCategorChartValue(){
$tst="";
$categories = Category::get();
$countCat = $categories->count();

for($i = 0;$i<=$countCat-1;$i++){
  $cat = Category::get();
  $sums = DB::table('sales')->where('category',$cat[$i]->id)->sum('total');

  $tst .= $sums .',';
}

  return $tst;
```

}

Comment: HINT: write that "algorithm" in form of a SQL query, and then you will se that is much more easy to understand how to create a Eloquent query that does what you want (and also for us to understand what you really want)

Answer (score 0):

Category::class

```
public function sales()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Sales::class);
}
```

Sales::class

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class); // category_id in the sales table
}
```

In your controller you can simply use [withCount()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models)

```
$categories = Category::select('id', 'name')->withCount('sales')->get()->toArray();

[
  0 => [
    "id" => 1,
    "name" => "Books",
    "sales_count" => 12
  ],
  .
  .
]
```